# ggplot facet_grid, code giving strange plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am pretty new to Rstudio, so excuse my cluelessness. 
I am trying to use faced_grid to display and compare a community structure. 
This is the code I'm having problems with:

```
ggplot(data= gjettj_occ_filter, 
        aes(x=gjettj_occ.ScientificName, y=gjettj_occ.maxant), color= gjettj_occ.Whitefish_presence,  
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
         gjettj_occ_filter$gjettj_occ.maxant ==0 + 
         geom_bar(stat = "summary") +
         facet_grid(gjettj_occ.LakeName~gjettj_occ.Depth))
```

Additional info:

1. gjettj_occ.ScientificName = non-numeric (Species names),
2. gjettj_occ.maxant = numeric (Number of individuals observed)
3. gjettj_occ.Whitefish_presence = non-numeric (Yes/no)
4. gjettj_occ.Depth = non-numeric (Deep/shallow)
5. gjettj_occ.LakeName = non-numeric (Site ID)

The goal is to investigate difference in community structure(maxant) in deep and shallow sediment(Depth), within one site(LakeName) to see if the presence of an introduced predator(Whitefish_presence) have had an effect.

My goal is to have the plot look something like this

[image: this].

But the plot I get from this code looks like this

[image: this].

What am I doing wrong?
Also, why is the text on the x-axis laying flat when the code asks for a 90 degree angle?

I have tried restarting, reinstalling packages and looking for updates, non seems to help.
Please let me know if there is need for more info.
Any help would be much appreciated!
-L

**DATA**

```
structure(list(gjettj_occ.LakeName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Gjettjonna", class = "factor"), 
    gjettj_occ.SlideNumber = c(4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 
    3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 
    3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 
    2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3), gjettj_occ.ScientificName = structure(c(5L, 
    2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
    10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 
    35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
    27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 
    33L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 
    37L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
    40L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 
    31L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
    42L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
    23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
    26L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    4L, 4L, 11L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    12L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 35L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 22L, 
    22L, 22L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 18L, 18L, 
    18L, 18L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 
    29L, 29L, 33L, 33L, 33L, 12L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 
    44L, 44L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 22L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 
    38L, 38L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 26L, 26L, 
    26L, 26L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 45L, 45L, 
    45L, 45L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 17L, 17L, 
    17L, 17L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 19L, 19L, 
    19L, 19L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 47L, 47L, 
    47L, 47L, 43L, 43L, 37L, 33L, 39L, 39L, 43L, 39L), .Label = c("Acropeus harpae", 
    "Alona affinis", "Alona costata", "Alona gutta", "Alona intermedia", 
    "Alona quadrangularis", "Alona rustica", "Alona sp.", "Alonella excisa", 
    "Alonella exigua", "Alonella nana", "Alonopsis elongata", 
    "Bosmina coregoni", "Bosmina longirostris", "Bosmina longispina", 
    "Bosmina sp.", "Bythotreptes", "Camptocercus", "Ceriodaphnia", 
    "Chyrodus gibbus", "Chyrodus sp.", "Chyrodus spaericus", 
    "Daphnia longispina", "Daphnia pulex", "Daphnia sp.", "Diaphanosoma", 
    "Disparalona rostrata", "Disparalona sp.", "Euricercus", 
    "Holopendium", "Latona", "Leydigia acanthocercoides", "Monospilus dispar", 
    "Ophryoxus cracilio", "Paralona pigra", "Paralona sp.", "Pleuroxus laevis", 
    "Pleuroxus trigonellus", "Pleuroxus truncatus", "Pleuroxus uncinatus", 
    "Polyhemus", "Polyhemus pediculus", "Rhynchotalona falcata", 
    "Rhynchotalona sp.", "Sida", "Sida crystallina", "Unidentified"
    ), class = "factor"), gjettj_occ.Depth = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("deep", "shallow"
    ), class = "factor"), gjettj_occ.maxant = c(0, 2, 5, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 
    41, 38, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 4, 
    6, 6, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 
    9, 9, 12, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 3, 6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 227, 285, 98, 300, 0, 110, 0, 
    159, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), gjettj_occ.Whitefish_presence = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "no", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-384L))
```

Comment: Please providing a reproducible example of your dataset (see this link: stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/…), e.g. type `dput(gjettj_occ_filter)` to your console and copy the output into your question. If your dataset is large, then simple give us a small example dataset, e.g. to extract only 20 rows of data type `dput(gjettj_occ_filter[1:20, ])` f

Comment: It looks like this line `gjettj_occ_filter$gjettj_occ.maxant ==0` is a bit weird in this context, what did you want to achieve with this?

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. 
Output have been added to text. 
The gjettj_occ_filter$gjettj_occ.maxant ==0 is added to exclude points on x-axis with no observations.

Comment: `gjettj_occ_filter$gjettj_occ.maxant ==0` will give a logical vector result, e.g., `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE...`, and `ggplot` has no idea what to do with it when you add it to a plot. Instead you should filter your data directly: `ggplot(data = gjettj_occ_filter[gjettj_occ_filter$gjettj_occ.maxant ==0, ], aes...`

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket in your `ggplot` **main call**. This and removing the peculiar already aforementioned line solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question!